# node-adodb returns empty set from Access DB, but mdb-sql works

Tags: node.js, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access database, which mdb-ver says is version 'JET4'.

Using the mdb-sql tool, I can query the database. But executing the same SQL query using the node-adodb package returns no data.

Any thoughts on this issue would be much appreciated. Thank you!

[**EDIT**] -- Thanks for the responses. Sorry for the omission. But the query is really very basic:

```
SELECT id, dob FROM patients WHERE FirstName='x' AND LastName='y'
```

Comment: Without knowing your secret query, it's not easy.

Comment: mdb-sql and node-adodb use a very different database engine. It's generally unlikely anything but a very basic query will work and return the same results on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad! Completely!

The `[npm package page][1]` showed a number of examples, and I glanced over them without understanding that the "query" method had to be explicitly used to get any results back. I used "execute" instead.